# Tkinter event based background label updating

Tags: python, tkinter, label, updating

My program is doing complex calculation that last for around 30 minutes. I would like to be updated about the values of some variables in a Tkinter GUI with ideally certain variables linked to certain labels so that they update automatically whenever they change their values. While I understand that I could create 2 threads (one for the main program and one for TKinter that calls itself every second or so), I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to handle this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

The below example shows how it could possibly look like, but the example doesn't work.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.counter = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.counter.pack()

        # start the clock "ticking"
        self.mainLoop()

    def mainLoop(self):
        for i in range (10000):
            j=i^2
            self.counter.configure(text=str(j))
            time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

However, it does work when the mainLoop is replaced with this:

```
def mainLoop(self):
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S" , time.gmtime())
    self.counter.configure(text=now)
    # call this function again in one second
    self.after(1000, self.mainLoop)
```

My questions:

1. Why does it work with "self.after" but not with a for loop
2. Is there a more elegant way to update labels event driven (not based on a button, but on a calculation that changes certain variables)

Comment: Did you try Googling for terms like "python tkinter after sleep"?

Answer (score 0):

To answer first question -

> Why does it work with "self.after" but not with a for loop

The `__init__()` method of a class is called when an object of that class in created. Now in your case, the class gets created in line -

```
app = SampleApp()
```

And in your `__init__()` , you call - `self.mainLoop()` .

In your `for` loop case, all this is running in the main thread. And so it would not return from the `self.mainLoop()` untill it has completed, since you are not start `self.mainLoop()` as a separate thread, you are doing that in the same thread. Hence, the control would reach the `root.mainloop()` line only after self.mainLoop()` has completed and returned the control back.

---

In case of using `after()` method, it behaves something like it registers an event to be fired after some amount of time, and immediately returns, it does not wait for that much amount of time and neither for the function to return. Hence the control immediately gets returned and it calls `root.mainloop()` to show the GUI.